# Install Open Hardware Monitor

Tags: software-installation

So I would like to install [Open Hardware Monitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/). I downloaded it and extracted the files (right-click, 'Extract here', not $sogijdsfg -xcv /sdflsa/rtyf). There's a .exe file but that only opens a folder with strange files. How do I install and run the program?

Comment: Linux cannot run EXE files.

Comment: If the EXE file is a .NET file, Linux can run it **natively** using Mono.

Answer (score 18):

As already said, you cannot install .exe win32 executables on Linux but please be informed that Open Hardware Monitor is also available for Linux, in fact:

> On Linux systems the Open Hardware Monitor requires Mono with WinForms.

http://openhardwaremonitor.org/downloads/

[image: Open Hardware Monitor on Linux]

```bash
# Install Mono
sudo apt install mono-complete

# Run Open Hardware Monitor:
mono OpenHardwareMonitor.exe
```

However, for those unwilling to do the above, you can use [psensor](https://launchpad.net/psensor) which is what I am using ATM on my main Ubuntu machine and is quite cool IMO

```bash
sudo apt install psensor
```

[image: Psensor is cool]

Comment: This is the correct answer, and the question is legit. If you came here, please upvote the question and this answer as it was unfairly downvoted by people who didn't take their time to read through it and give a proper answer.

Comment: @BrunoFinger I tried to do so but no data was displayerd. See my results here: https://photos.app.goo.gl/MwfY3cpLCnbw7JqK7

Comment: hi @Wingarmac could you please provide details on your machine, OS as well as the installation procedure you followed so that I can try to replicate that?

Comment: @BrunoFinger I'm using lubuntu 22.04 LTS. I didn't create a wine prefix. Just installed wine-stable and followed the steps you suggested. After that, right click and "open with mono runtime" the exe file.
wine install procedure followed : https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

Comment: @Wingarmac I think you are overcomplicating the process. You really do not need the .NET Framework to read hardware data, thus I'd suggest to use Psensor and forget about OHM. this is especially good on Lubuntu (which I used for quite some time). It's a great lightweight distro, so don't bloat it. Please see my edited response.
BTW I'm not BrunoFinger lol

Comment: @BrunoFinger I agree with you're other suggestion, but the suggested solution to make Open Hardware Monitor work, didn't. That's the title of the question. Not :"What application could be used instead?" I was interested in more details to make it work like in the screenshot you'll published.

Comment: Hi, this might be a dumb question, but which option corresponds to the actual CPU temperature? I have an option called "composite" that I think is the cpu temp but I'm not sure.